# how to npm i properly cloned repo

Tags: git, github, npm, git-clone

trying to use this portfolio template

https://github.com/saadpasta/developerFolio

```
# Clone this repository
git clone https://github.com/saadpasta/developerFolio.git

# Go into the repository
cd developerFolio

# Setup default environment variables

# For Windows
copy env.example .env

# Install dependencies
npm install

# Start a local dev server
npm start
```

I originally cloned it without forked but figured that was wrong. So forked then cloned and tried again but still got same error.

when I npm i

-get error "Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists."

I didnt see anything else in the instructions for the readme and dont have much git experience. So Im guessing its some basic github/git step im missing?

Answer (score 0):

found answer in QA of Repo. Deleted package-lock.json and npm i worked

Comment: Deleting `package-lock.json` without a compelling reason reason (and a thorough understanding of the implications) is not a very good idea.